# Generate score with Javascript | The smaller the number -> the higher the score

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to generate a score with JavaScript where the smaller the number inputted the higher the score. It doesn't really matter how it works I just want something that could give similar output to this or just any similar inverse proportion thing.

```
Input: 20 -> Output 210
Input: 400 -> Output 55
Input: 50 -> Output 175
```

Just something similar to this. If possible, please provide a function in your answer.

Comment: does it have limits ? what input would output 0. and if input was 0 what would the output be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a linear approach, you could take a slope with an adjusted value and add an offset later.

```js
function score(v) {
    return (v - 20) * -155 / 380 + 210;
}

console.log(score(20));  // 210
console.log(score(400)); //  55

console.log(score(50));  // 175
```

Comment: Lifesaver, thank you

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz. Thanks for your answer. How would I make it so a number like 5000 or 6000 wouldn't output a negative number, but just a really low score like 4 or 5. Thanks so much!!

Comment: this is a bit more complicated. maybe you try with a logarithm of the number and adjust some other values.